# How to read .xls specific cell data using GemBox in c#

Tags: c#, excel, gembox-spreadsheet

Please help me to fetch or to read specific cell data of .xls spreed sheet using GemBox in c#.

I am able to write but fails to read the specific cell data.

I don't want to read all data at once.

```
var dataSet = new DataSet();
        SpreadsheetInfo.SetLicense("FREE-LIMITED-KEY");
        GemBox.Spreadsheet.ExcelFile ef = new GemBox.Spreadsheet.ExcelFile();
       // ExcelFile ef = ExcelFile.Load(@"C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\100sitesSpreedSheet.xls");
        ef = GemBox.Spreadsheet.ExcelFile.Load(@"C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\100sitesSpreedSheet.xls");
        ExcelWorksheet ws = ef.Worksheets["100sitesSpreadSheet"];
        ws.Cells[6, 0].Value = "abcd";
        ef.Save(@"C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\100sitesSpreedSheet.xls");
```

Comment: Show your work and tell us what have you tried and where you stuck.

Comment: Updated your code in your question with `edit` button under your question.

Comment: M sorry my code may look hapazard, but I am not able to post it in synchronised manner.. The above code writes data to specific cell, but how to read data from same specific cell or from other cell

Comment: I think I got the way, I simply tried.. `Console.WriteLine((ws.Cells["A7"].GetFormattedValue()));`

Answer (score 0):

to read the specific cell's value you can just use the [Value property](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/help/html/P_GemBox_Spreadsheet_ExcelCell_Value.htm), like the following:

```
Console.WriteLine(ws.Cells["A7"].Value);
```

This property is of an object type and can return a text or a number or a date, depending on the data it stores. Also note that [GetFormattedValue method](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/help/html/M_GemBox_Spreadsheet_ExcelCell_GetFormattedValue.htm) actually converts that value into a string representation by using a number format which is applied to that cell.